# laravel form text with value extension

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I have a form where there's a field that is disabled and contains a dynamic value gathered from a class function, code looks like this:

```
{!! Form::input('number', 'estimate', Estimate::getTotal($userId), ['class' => 'form-control', 'disabled']) !!}
```

Now what I want to accomplish is to add a static currency string, like 'USD', after it. So the textfield would contain "5000 USD", instead of the just the number. How can I do that?

Oh and the function looks like this:

```
public static function getTotal($userId)
{
    $estimates = self::whereNull('case_id')->where('user_id', '=', $userId)->get();
    $total = 0;

    foreach ($estimates as $estimate){
        $rate = Competence::where('id', $estimate->competence_id)->first()->hourely_rate;
        $total = $total + $estimate->hours * $rate;
    }

    return $total;
}
```

Comment: `$total = $total. ' USD'`?

Comment: or append the ` USD` in the view: `Estimate::getTotal($userId).' USD'`

Comment: Both of those makes it return nothing in the view I'm affraid.

Comment: make sure `Estimate::getTotal($userId)` actually returns value rather then `null`. May be by `var_dump(Estimate::getTotal($userId))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an `number` input type, pretty self explaining that this input can't contain a string. Change the type to `text` and simply use:

```
Estimate::getTotal($userId) . ' USD'
```

You could also edit your function to return the total amount plus the currency.

Comment: I totally forgot to take that into consideration. Thanks!